# Real-time data warehouse: Event-driven vs Polling

Tags: real-time, data-warehouse, production-environment

I know this question has been asked before at [PostgreSQL to Data-Warehouse: Best approach for near-real-time ETL / extraction of data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2519985/postgresql-to-data-warehouse-best-approach-for-near-real-time-etl-extraction).
But I want to rephrase this question.

I am attempting a real-time data warehouse. The difference between real-time and near real-time is huge.
I find real-time data warehouse to be event-driven and transactional in approach.
While near real-time would do the same batch mode application but would poll data more frequently. 
It would put so much extra load on the production server and would certainly kill the production system. 
Being a batch approach it would scan through all the tables for changes and would take rows which have changed from 
a cut-off time stamp.
I mean by event driven, it would be specific to tables which have undergone changes are focus only on transaction 
which are happening currently.

But the source system is an elephant of system, SAP, assuming which has 25,000 tables. It is not easy to model that, 
not easy to write database triggers on each table to capture each change. I want impact on the production server to be minimal.

Is there any trigger at database level so that I could capture all changes happening in database in one trigger.
Is there any way to write that database trigger on a different database server so that production server goes untouched.
I have not been keeping pace with changes happening to database technology and am sure some nice new technologies would have come by to capture these changes easily.

I know of Log miners and Change data captures but it would be difficult to filter out the information which I need from redo logs.
Alternate ways to capture database write operations on the go.

Just for completeness sake let us assume databases are a heterogeneous mix of Oracle, SQL Server and DB2. But my contention is
the concepts we want to develop.

This is a universal problem, every company is looking for easy to implement solution. So a good discussion would benefit all.

Comment: Your question is interesting, but impossible to answer precisely; SO is not for discussions.

Comment: Are you saying when someone makes a change in SAP you want that change to instantly appear in a data warehouse? What purpose does that server when someone still needs to run a report on it?

Comment: As of now I can see only two solutions:

Answer (score 1):

Don't ever try to access SAP directly. Use the APIs of SAP Data Services (http://help.sap.com/bods). Look for the words "Integrator Guide" on that page for documentation.

This document should give you a good hint about where to look for your data sources (http://wiki.scn.sap.com/wiki/display/EIM/What+Extractors+to+use). Extractors are kind-of-somewhat like views in a DBMS, they're abstracting all the SAP stuff into somethin human readable.

As far as near-real-time, think in terms of micro-batches. Run your extract jobs every 5 (?) minutes, or longer if necessary.

Comment: I agree, as I wouldn't like to maintain triggers on a SAP version upgrade

Answer (score 0):

Check the *Lambda Architecture from Nathan Marz* (I provide no link, but you'll find the resources easily). The implementation is all Java and No SQl, but the main ideas are applicable to the classical relational databases as well. In the nutshell: you have two implementations, one real time but responsible for only limited time interval. The "long tail" is maintained with classical best practice batch implementation.

The real time part is always discarded after the batch refresh, effectively blocking the propagation of the problems of the real time processing in the historical data.

Answer (score 0):

As Ron pointed out NEVER TOUCH SAP TABLE DIRECTLY. There are adapters and adapters to access SAP tables. This will build another layer in between but it is unavoidable. One good news I want to share is a customer did a study of SAP tables and found that only 14% of the tables are actually populated or touched by SAP system. Even then 14% of 25,000 tables is coming to huge data model of 2000+ entities. Again micro-batches are like dividing the system into Purchase, Receivables, Payables etc., which is heading for a data mart and not an EDW. I want to focus on a Enterprise Data Warehouse.

Comment: Microbatches does not require dividing the system. It is virtually the same ETL/ELT architecture as a daily batch, but run many times throughout the day. In terms of the two options you put, microbatches are closest to polling. This is your best option in a high transaction rate system, as the speed to ingest batches of data can be orders of magnitude faster than the speed to process the same volume of single record inserts.

Answer (score 0):

As of now I can see only two solutions:

1. Write services on the source systems. If source is COBOL, put those in services. Put all services in a service bus and 
   some how trap when changes happen to database. This needs to be explored how that trap will work. 
   But from outset it appears to be a very 
   expensive proposition and uncertain. Convincing management for a three year lag time would be difficult. Services are not easy.
2. Log Shippers: This a trusted database solution. Logs would be available on another server, production server need not be 
   burdened. There are good number of tools as well available. 
   But the spirit does not match. Event driven is missing so the action when things 
   are happening is not captured. I will settle down for this.